# Blink td in explorer using CSS

Tags: css, html

I am using a CSS class to blink td

```
.blink {
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

but this does not work in explorer. Can anyone please help how to achieve blinking through CSS.

Comment: I think Animation is not working/supported in IE.

Comment: you can do it in IE 11 though

Comment: I didn't find any alternative for explorer to implement this through CSS. I am using IE 11 and it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you can see from here [`link`](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation)

the property animation doesn't work on IE8/9.
If it doesn't work with IE 10+, you can use this code (I remember you that if you use a prefix css you must declare a property without -prefix- too), in your code there was any error.
With this code shoulds work on IE10 and all browser.

```
.blink {
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -ms-animation-name: blink;
    -o-animation-name: blink;
    animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I placed above code but till it didn't work. Please let me know if you have other alternative

Comment: Have you set the @keyframes blink?

Comment: Yes I realized that late to set the Keyframe.. It is working now...thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Ok, you can put like to my answer? Please bro

Answer (score 1):

You're using a -webkit specific syntax...IE doesn't run on Webkit.

Use the non-prefixed version as well.

```
.blink {
   -webkit-animation-name: blink;
           animation-name: blink;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
           animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
           animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
           animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I placed above code but till it didn't work. Please let me know if you have other alternative

Comment: You'll have to show us the whole problem in a demo. Did you test in any other browsers? We'd need to see the keyframes too.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I forgot setting my keyframe in the CSS.. I set the keyframe and it is working as expected.. thanks once again..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution..
    .blink {
       -webkit-animation-name: blink;
           animation-name: blink;
       -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
           animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
           animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
       -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
           animation-duration: 1s;
    }

```
@keyframes blink {
 from {
    opacity: 1.0;
    }
 to {
    opacity: 0.0;
    }
}
```